# Mongoose - Return object only if condition matches all the objects in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Description:

I want to only return if all the objects in the array match the condition. Now, it's returning the object if at least one condition matches in the array of objects.

If you guys have any more queries regarding this question. I will answer please ask!

Input:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"4",
      "intends":[
         {
            "_id":"1",
            "status":"Packed"
         },
         {
            "_id":"2",
            "status":"Packed"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"5",
      "intends":[
         {
            "_id":"3",
            "status":"Packed"
         },
         {
            "_id":"4",
            "status":"Created"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Current Output:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"4",
      "intends":[
         {
            "_id":"1",
            "status":"Packed"
         },
         {
            "_id":"2",
            "status":"Packed"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"5",
      "intends":[
         {
            "_id":"3",
            "status":"Packed"
         },
         {
            "_id":"4",
            "status":"Created"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"4",
      "intends":[
         {
            "_id":"1",
            "status":"Packed"
         },
         {
            "_id":"2",
            "status":"Packed"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I have tried:

```
db.collection.find({intends.status: "Packed"})
db.collection.find({intends: {$elemMatch: {status: "Packed"}}})
```

Comment: so you need records of when every value of intends has status Packed?

Comment: Exactly I want that. I also posted the expected result.

Comment: FYI, Have also tried with $elemMatch... Please check the updated question.

Comment: updated answer. use ne instead of nin since you are only searching one value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution using `$elemMatch`, `$nin` and `$not`.
The `$elemMatch`, `$nin` part will give all elements where there is at least one element with status not "Packed". So the `$not` will reverse it and give elements where every status is "Packed"

```js
db.collection.find({
  intends: {
    "$not": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        status: {
          "$nin": [
            "Packed"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GYlkkcIiwRT)

**UPDATE**
Since here just checking 1 value use `$ne` instead of `$nin`

```js
db.collection.find({
  intends: {
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {
        status: {
          $ne: "Packed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XBFfVbOPTNQ)

Answer (score 0):

using `aggregation` [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) and [$allElementsTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/)

test it at [mongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HeBVUGxYtw-)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$redact": {
      "$cond": [
        {
          "$allElementsTrue": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$intends",
              "as": "intend",
              "in": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$intend.status",
                  "Packed"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "$$KEEP",
        "$$PRUNE"
      ]
    }
  }
])
```